Explode multiple columns in pandas dataframe
I am trying to explode below dataframe based on a delimiter '|'.
    preferred_title_symbol                      mim_number  MDR_code    MDR_term    
0   17-BETA HYDROXYSTEROID DEHYDROGENASE III    264300.0    10037122    pseudohermaphroditism   
1   2,4-DIENOYL-CoA REDUCTASE DEFICIENCY        616034.0    10027417 | 10081311 | 10059750  leukodystrophy | metabolic acidosis | muscle retention  

The expected output is this:
    preferred_title_symbol                      mim_number  MDR_code    MDR_term    
0   17-BETA HYDROXYSTEROID DEHYDROGENASE III    264300.0    10037122    pseudohermaphroditism   
1   2,4-DIENOYL-CoA REDUCTASE DEFICIENCY        616034.0    10027417    leukodystrophy 
1   2,4-DIENOYL-CoA REDUCTASE DEFICIENCY        616034.0    10081311    metabolic acidosis 
1   2,4-DIENOYL-CoA REDUCTASE DEFICIENCY        616034.0    10059750    muscle retention

I am using below code to do that.
out = (
        pd.concat([df[col].str.split("\|")
                          .explode() for col in ["MDR_code", "MDR_term"]], axis=1)
             .join(df["preferred_title_symbol"])
      )

However i get below error:
ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels
How can I achieve the desired output.

you need to explode the whole dataframe using the column as a parameter
import pandas as pd

data = [{
    'preferred_title_symbol': '4-DIENOYL-CoA REDUCTASE DEFICIENCY ',
    'mim_number': 616034.0,
    'MDR_code': '10027417 | 10081311 | 10059750',
    'MDR_term': 'leukodystrophy | metabolic acidosis | muscle retention'
}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


df['MDR_code'] = df['MDR_code'].str.split(' | ')
df['MDR_term'] = df['MDR_term'].str.split(' | ')


df = df.explode('MDR_code').explode('MDR_term')

print(df)


calm down drama queen, i only forgot to add \ on the split, with it, everything work fine :)
